# mysql process constantly overload

Tags: mysql, overloading, cpu

i properly asking a question that do not have an answer, but i am out of resources and have to try any mean that possible to have a way to solve this problem. first off. i ain't programmer, i just an online store staff that assign to deal with the server and stuff like that. i have basic knowledge to cpanel, whm, but no experience in programming.

we see our server is very very slow recently, i go in whm and see the cpu usage constantly stay like 200% up to 2000% (yes, 2000%) from time to time, then i looked into the process manager and see one particular line that border me:

pid991 - this use like at least 100% of the cpu most of the time i look and the command is

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/www.(domain).com.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/www.(domain).com.pid
```

and if i go into trace, i see this code repeat again and again

```
>fcntl(12, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
>fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
>accept(12, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 95
>fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)              = 0
>getsockname(95, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"}, [28]) = 0
>gettimeofday({1380692546, 638961}, NULL) = 0
>fcntl(95, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY)            = 0
>fcntl(95, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
>setsockopt(95, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, "\36\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
>setsockopt(95, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, "<\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 0
>fcntl(95, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
>setsockopt(95, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4)  = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
>gettimeofday({1380692546, 641571}, NULL) = 0
>clone(child_stack=0x7ff0ead58ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7ff0ead599d0, tls=0x7ff0ead59700, child_tidptr=0x7ff0ead599d0) = 6590
>poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN}])
```

with only difference in the number string and may be some ids. i actually have a programmer here, but he is a freelancer and keep tell us he doesn't know what happen, so...

1. can we know what this is doing with only these repeat lines of ode?
2. there is a kill button in process manager, is it safe to simply kill the process?

thank you for your help!

Comment: make sure you're killing the correct process or else..

Comment: thanks, i see the kill button, but without knowing what it does, don't know if this is safe to force kill it

Comment: btw what does this process do?

Comment: it would be great if i can tell -.-

Answer (score 0):

The trace messages do not identify the cause of your performance problem. See https://serverfault.com/questions/374120/setsockopt-eopnotsupp-operation-not-supported

It's not safe to simply kill that process; that is your MySQL database, so I expect that if you kill the process, your website will go down.

It's quite likely that you have long-running queries or just a huge volume of database activity on that server, so you'll need to investigate in that direction rather than in the trace. Start with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in the MySQL console to see what's currently running and for how long, and that should point you in the direction of statements and connections to look at.

Comment: well, it shows it is taking up +100% cpu most of the time, that's why i have the suspection. while i don't familiar with those sql stuff, i'll try to get the command line client and take a look, see i can dig up something myself. thanks!